# data loader in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react app where I have routes set up with the new data loaders from `react-router-dom`

```
import {
  RouterProvider,
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import { rootLoader } from './loaders/rootLoader';
import { WelcomePage } from './components/Home';
import Pokemon from './components/Pokemon';
import { pokemonLoader } from './loaders/pokemonLoader';
import Error from './error/Error';
import './App.css';

const router2 = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements([
    <Route
      element={<Home />}
      loader={rootLoader}
      path='/'
      errorElement={<Error />}
    >
      <Route element={<WelcomePage />} index />
      <Route
        element={<Pokemon />}
        loader={pokemonLoader}
        path='pokemon/:name'
      />
    </Route>
  ]
))

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router2} />
}

export default App;
```

The issue I have is the loader runs whenever a request is made from one of the routes children, e.g when I am on the welcome page, and I navigate to the Pokemon page, the `rootLoader` runs every single time on the parent route even when I am not using it on that page.

Is there a way to stop this? Is this the desired behaviour or is `useEffect` better in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. If you are manually updating the URL in the address bar this reloads the entire app. When the URL path is `"/pokemon/<some pokemon id>"` both the `Home` layout route ***and*** the `Pokemon` routes are loaded and will run their loader functions.

To resolve this you just need to actually ***navigate*** to the individual pokemon pages from within the app. For example, by rendering a navbar/links in `Home` that navigate to the specific pokemon pages.

### Demo

[image: Edit data-loader-in-react-router]

Example output, the initial load with the root loader, then clicking through each link produces exactly 1 pokemon loader log per navigation.

[image]